# Where is the save files directory?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I have been searching for the save files directory for Tomb Raider 2013. However, I was not able to find it.

Does anyone know where the save files are stored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This differs depending on the version of the game you've got. I got my copy of Tomb Raider via Steam, and my saves folder is located here;

`Steam Folder\userdata\<profile id>\203160\remote`

For any other release of the game (retail box or Origin) the saves will probably be located here;

`C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Square Enix`

Comment: Hmm.... still can't find it......

Comment: Well try searching for `profile.dat` and `save1.dat` etc, those are the names of the files stored within this folder